# WKWebView evaluateJavaScript only working when view is disappeared swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a webview attached to a UIViewController. I am making a music app. Everytime the app goes into the background the music plays (desired.) However, if I have the UIViewController that contains the webview is present, it does not. Why is this? Is there a delegate method to find out what's going on here?

I have already tried:

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
```

and

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
```

I get the error every time the play function runs:

> JavaScript execution returned a result of an unsupported type

Yet the play func works just not in the above scenarios.

WKWebview is the source of the streaming. The way playerView is created is like this:

```
let popupContentController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlayerViewController") as! PlayerViewController
tabBarController?.presentPopupBar(withContentViewController: popupContentController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I suspect it is a navigation stack issue. Again, the issue doesn't happen when the playerView is dismissed.

Comment: Can you tell us how is webview being used? Is the music streaming inside webview?

Comment: see edit :) @RikeshSubedi

Comment: One way to see what's happening in WebView is to remotely debug in Safari. You can see what's going on inside it. Check for Safari on iOS https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html